# PHP MYSQL : fgetcsv : Is there any maximum number of lines?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, max, fgetcsv

I'm facing a little disturbance :

I'm importing data from csv to Mysql via PHP, using `fgetcsv()`
Today, my CSV file is  **150 000 lines (or rows) long**, but it could be longer.

Do you have any idea if there is a **maximum number of lines** authorized for the CSV file,  set for a `fgetcsv()` operation ?

I thought of 5000 lines max (someone told me so one day), but I could not find any source which could alleged that.

EDIT -- here is a better explanation (i hope) and my code :

I'm **not** talking about "file size limitations" here, but about **maximum number of rows**, which is slightly different, yet i recognize that the number of rows can increase the file size. I've already searched the internet, and did not found any valuable answer to this question, nor "there is no number of row limitations", nor "there is a limitation"...

```
    $fileName = "MyFileName";
    $fileExtension = ".csv";
    $filePath = "My/Path/To/My/CSV";
    $link = $filePath.$fileName.$fileExtension;
    if (file_exists($link))
    {
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Import PM - 01");
            if(($handle = fopen($link, 'r')) !== FALSE)
            {
                $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Import PM - 02");
                while(($raw_data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';')) !== FALSE)
                { 
                    //read one line after the other, and execute my code
                 } 

             }
       }
```

I am trying to import that in sugarCRM (that's for the strange log)

Comment: ***Pro tip:*** Do not act needy and do not say your requirement is urgent. The folks answering questions are volunteers with busy lives, just like yours.

Comment: There is a time limit setting in PHP for processing, but there is no limit on the number of lines in a CSV file. You could also be held back by memory limitations.

Comment: May we see your code, and the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard for your tips, I've always done like that, in fact (except for the urgent), because i believe we can be polite to each other for every folks has a busy life juste like me.
Okay, so the person who told me that there was a limitation in the number of lines (5000 was his number) was wrong? So, i guess the memory limit set in php.ini you're thinking of is memory_limit, maybe upload_max_filesize and max_execution_time ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for your time @halfer, i've edited my question with my code.
As you  can see, there is nothing strange in it. My question was really "but what if my .csv file is longer than 5000 rows?"

Comment: Various programs can have problems *reading* a 150000-row CSV (MS Excel, notably), but no, I have both read and writtend CSVs with millions of rows in PHP. If you're getting any errors (are you getting any errors? What are they?), they're not related to CSV specifically.

Comment: Thanks @Piskvor for your answer, i'll try and ask directly to sugarCRM, though it is not a program, technically speaking. i'm not getting any errors, because i haven't tried yet (it will certainly take some big time to run), but it is a possibility, and my customer asked me to be assured of being able to read such big files

Comment: I would recommend just going ahead and writing it - SugarCRM devs will say the same. A script may take a long time to process a large CSV file, but it absolutely can be made to work.